# Boost.Regex with icu/unicode support

Tags: c++, boost, unicode, icu, gcc-warning

How to build Boost.Regex with icu/ unicode support? My compiler is GCC, and IDE is Eclipse C++. How to configure binary files with Eclipse?
I  tried to do this "bjam --sHAVE_ICU=1 toolset=gcc". But it did not work.
When i check if icu support is enable with "bjam -has_icu", i still get "has icu builds : no".

Answer (score 5):

I build Boost against ICU using `-sICU_PATH=<icuRoot>` and `-sICU_LINK="-L<icuLibDir>"`.

I've seen Boost fail to properly detect ICU as well, and have needed to patch the file has_icu_test.cpp (simply return 0 from it's main() function). This will work if you know everything else is set up properly.

Comment: Where is icuRoot and icuLibDir? Are they both /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig?

Comment: @JasonStack These are _your_ paths -- that is, where you have built ICU.

Comment: I have built ICU using ./configure --prefix=/usr/local, so should I give /usr/local as icuRoot?

Comment: --prefix is used for installation. If you're building for Android, you're going to want a local path to simply place binaries (that you'll later use on the device)

Comment: I am building Aegisub for Fedora 24, but every time it complains about lack of ICU-supporting boost. Building boost and ICU from source did not help either. I have opened a question thread [here](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/94430/cannot-build-aegisub-in-fedora-configure-error-aegisub-requires-that-boost-be-built-with-icu-support/?comment=94439#comment-94439)

Comment: trying to build 1.67 i find that  -sICU_PATH is no longer accepted as parameter

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem by adding directly include path of include ICU directory to cflags when executing b2. For instance:

```
./b2 --with-regex
cflags="-O0 -I\"$ICU_PATH/include\"
```

You also may need to add path of ICU lib and moreover full paths to libs to linker. Something like this:

```
export ICU_LINK="-L\"$ICU_PATH/lib\" -l\"$ICU_PATH/lib/libicudata.a\" -l\"$ICU_PATH/lib/libicui18n.a\" -l\"$ICU_PATH/lib/libicuuc.a\""
./b2 --with-regex
cflags="-O0 -I\"$ICU_PATH/include\"
-sICU_LINK=$ICU_LINK \
```

Answer (score 0):

### Behemoths and Juggernauts

On some unix, this worked for me:

`./b2 link=static,shared -sICU_PATH=/usr/local install`

In said system, ICU headers are installed in `/usr/local/include` and ICU libraries in `/usr/local/lib`

In order to test if you have ICU headers installed (say in `/usr/local/include`) see if the dir `/usr/local/include/unicode/` exists and has lots of header files in it (e.g. `symtable.h`)

**Note** that when I followed general advice from then net and passed `-sICU_LINK='-L/usr/local/lib'` to boost's `b2`, ICU detection (version 1.62 and 1.63) failed.

In the previous answer, user "NuSkooler" mentions that patching boost file `has_icu_test.cpp` to simply `return 0;` short-circuits the test and boost believes all is genkhi with ICU and goes ahead with it.

**However** make sure you also **delete** all ICU-related function calls and header files from that file because it is usually the case that `has_icu_test.cpp` first fails to compile or link because ICU libraries or header files can not be found by boost internals.

With all these, I can confirm that Aegisub's `configure` now passes the ICU test for me.

(and all these because John Hurt sadly died and I tried to put subtitles in a clip of `Heaven's Gate` to give to a friend)

b.